# Syntax Error when adding a table via Flyway

Tags: sql, syntax

I created a `.sql` file which init the tables using fylway.

I get the following syntax error, does any one has an idea what is wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCTS
(
    ID                     INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CREATE_DATE            DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL,
    SKU                    VARCHAR(250)     NULL,
    ORDER_NUMBER           VARCHAR(255)     NULL,
    EAN                    VARCHAR(255)     NULL,
    MPN                    VARCHAR(255)     NULL,
    QTY                    INT              NULL,
    STATUS                 BIT              NULL,
    TEMP_STATUS            BIT              NULL,
    WEBSHOP_ACTIVE         BIT              NULL,
    NAME_DE                VARCHAR(500)     NULL,
    DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DE   VARCHAR(2500)    NULL,
    DESCRIPTION_LONG_DE    TEXT             NULL,
    MANUFACTURER_ID        INT              NULL,
    CATEGORY_ID            INT              NULL,
    INVENTORY_LOCATION_ID  INT              NULL,
    PRICE_TEMPLATE_ID      INT              NULL,
    PURCHASE_PRICE         DOUBLE(10,[*] 2) NULL,
    UVP_PRICE              DOUBLE(10, 2)    NULL,
    SALES_PRICE_CALCULATED DOUBLE(10, 2)    NULL,
    SALES_PRICE_MANUAL     DOUBLE(10, 2)    NULL,
    VPE_CONTENT            DECIMAL(10, 2)   NULL,
    WEIGHT_GRAM            DECIMAL(10, 2)   NULL,
    PARENT                 BIT              NULL,
    TAX_CLASS_ID           INT              NULL
);
```

The error is:

> Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCTS ..."
>
> )"; expected ")"*

Comment: PURCHASE_PRICE         DOUBLE(10,[*] 2)     strange construction. What does it mean?

Comment: Which flavour of SQL (DBMS)? Double likely doesn't have two parameters.

Comment: Thank you   Must be a mistake by my MySQL client. I created the database by client and then exported the schema creation script 

Comment: i checked it, but thats not the reason. It must be a copy paste issue. In my Code it looks like this
purchase_price         double(10, 2)                      null,

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that H2 database is not 100% compatible to sql scripts using with mysql database.